# Как реализовать аналог механизма исключений

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования, исключения

Рассмотрим такую задачу на абстрактном объектно ориентированном языке программирования:

Есть объект **Reply** который умеет отображать текстовое сообщение и объект **BlackBox** с некоторыми методами, возвращающими **Reply**:

```
class Reply {
  string display()
}

class BlackBox {
  Reply doActionOne()
  Reply doActionTwo()
  Reply doActionThree()
  ...
}
```

Методы **doAction** делают сложные цепочки вызовов:

```
...
Reply doActionTwo() {
   someOtherObjects->do->some->stuff();
}
...
```

При этом в каждом звене цепочки может сформироваться **Reply**, который нужно сразу вернуть, не вызывая дальнейший код. Приходится писать такие простыни:

```
...
Reply doActionTwo() {
   reply = checkSomeOneStuff();
   if(reply != null)
      return reply

   reply = checkAnotherStuff();
   if(reply != null)
      return reply

   reply = checkSomeOtherStuff();
   if(reply != null)
      return reply

   reply = checkSomeOtherOtherStuff();
   if(reply != null)
      return reply
}
...
```

Если ли какие нибудь известные паттерны или красивые приемы реализации исключений, чтобы логика кода была примерно такая:

```
...
Reply doActionTwo() {
   try {
     checkSomeOneStuff();
     checkAnotherStuff();
     checkSomeOtherStuff();
     checkSomeOtherOtherStuff();
   } catch(Reply fired) {
     return fired
   }
}
...
```

Comment: Например, вы можете реализовать исключения как монаду: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772727/exception-or-either-monad-in-c-sharp

Comment: Не понял, а исключения чем не устраивают?

Comment: @dzhioev: например, тем, что их нету в языке X.

Comment: реализовал через монаду, спасибо!